# iterate a List<HashMap<String, String>> values using java

Tags: java

I have a json response like this

```
{
  "queryPath": "/api/",
  "nId": "f084f5ad24fcfaa9e9faea0",
  "statusCode": 707
  "statusMessage": "Success",
  "results": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "10248522500798",
        "capabilities": [
          "men",
          "women"
        ],
        "name": "errt2"
      },
      {
        "id": "418143778",
        "capabilities": [
          "dog",
          "cat"
        ],
        "name": "Livin"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here am adding `results.data` to a list as follows

```
  private List<HashMap<String, String>> episodes = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
  episodes =helper.getJSONValue(response, "results.data"); 



   public <T>T getJSONValue(Response res, String path ){
        String json = res.asString();
        JsonPath jpath = new JsonPath(json);
        return jpath.get(path);
    }
```

so episodes contains all data i mean all results.data
While i debuging am getting this way

```
 [{id=10248522500798, name=errt2, capabilities=[men, women]}, {id=418143778, name=Livin, capabilities=[dog, cat]}]
```

Here i have capabilities `[men, women]` and `[dog, cat]`.i need to check capability contains `men` or `dog.`
How can i do that?

Comment: Why do you need `List<HashMap<String, String>> ` ?

Comment: then how it can do.am new to java.please provide me a simple solution for this

Comment: actulayy that method  getJSONValue is a common one..dats y am using like this...so i have to use like this List<HashMap<String, String>>

Comment: my intention is to search that values like men and dog with already exiting values of capabilities array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i were you i haven't done this..
Use [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) and map your json into a java model. It's way better. Afterwards you can access all your model parts with getters and setters.

```
 MyType target2 = gson.fromJson(json, MyType.class); // deserializes json into target2
```

As you see it's very simple :)

But if you want to iterate a list that contains a map you can use code block below:

```
List<Map<String, String>> test = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for( Map<String, String> map : test ){
            for( Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet() ){
                System.out.println( entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue() );
            }
        }
```

With the code above you can get all the entry's keys and values and check them.

**Edit:**

You have to change your List to `List<Map<String,Object>>` after that:

```
 List<Map<String, Object>> test = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
        for( Map<String, Object> map : test ){
            for( Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet() ){
                if( entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase( "capabilities" ) ){
                    List<String> myCapabilities = ( List )entry.getValue();
                    if( myCapabilities.contains( "dog" ) && myCapabilities.contains( "cat" ) ){
                        // BLA BLA
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

It's a nasty way.. I recommend you to use gson..

Comment: this code will check the values of capability array [men, women] and [dog, cat]with another value (for eg men)